# TestCafe: After updating started to fail on await t.debug() RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Out of nowhere i started to get this error message, when I try to use await t.debug()

have not changed anything on my code. I started to work on a new task and upgraded the testcafe to a new version, and now it always fails when doing debug. The code without debug runs fine.

```
internal/console/constructor.js:291
          throw e;
          ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at WriteStream.overriddenWrite [as write] (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/log-update-async-hook/src/index.js:19:16)
    at WriteStream.stream.write (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/testcafe/src/notifications/debug-logger.js:19:30)
    at WriteStream.overriddenWrite [as write] (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/log-update-async-hook/src/index.js:22:31)
    at WriteStream.stream.write (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/testcafe/src/notifications/debug-logger.js:19:30)
    at WriteStream.overriddenWrite [as write] (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/log-update-async-hook/src/index.js:22:31)
    at WriteStream.stream.write (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/testcafe/src/notifications/debug-logger.js:19:30)
    at WriteStream.overriddenWrite [as write] (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/log-update-async-hook/src/index.js:22:31)
    at WriteStream.stream.write (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/testcafe/src/notifications/debug-logger.js:19:30)
    at WriteStream.overriddenWrite [as write] (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/log-update-async-hook/src/index.js:22:31)
    at WriteStream.stream.write (/Users/pavelgusilic/Documents/GitHub/e2e/node_modules/testcafe/src/notifications/debug-logger.js:19:30)
```

Answer (score 1):

See the progress and detailed information about this issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6906.